Simple derivative question of $y(x)=\exp(a_0+a_1x+\ldots +a_n x^n)$
How would one find the general $y^{(n)}(x)$, i.e the $n$-th derivative of $y(x)=\exp(a_0+a_1x+\ldots+ a_n x^n)$?
Can Mathematica software handle this?
Thanks in advance!

An idea, write $f(x)=e^{P(x)}=\sum b_nx^n$ and report in $f'(x)=P'(x)f(x)$ you'll get an induction relation for the $b_n$. Most probably Bernoulli numbers will be involved.

Is it the same $n$ in $\exp(a_0+a_1x+\ldots a_n x^n)$ and in $y^{(n)} (x)$ ?

@Andreas yes it's the same.
